# Eclipse debugging - any way to pass in "extras" for launching intent?

Tags: android

I'm developing Activity which works on data passed in Intent in extras.
This Activity is supposed to be launched by other activities in my app.

However, during development/debugging, I launch this Activity directly, and want to simulate extras in Intent (obtained from getIntent) to pass in desired testing params (sort of command-line parameters).

In Eclipse Run configurations, I can just select Launch action, but no additional data.

Is there some way? Or I must hardcode testing params in java, and not forget to comment them out when testing is finished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think eclipse is just using something comparable to the *am start* method to launch an application.  You should be able to do this manually via adb and specify extras; then once you have it working from the command line you can put it behind a button using eclipse's extensibility features.

Here's a writeup found during a brief search: http://learnandroid.blogspot.com/2008/01/run-android-application-from-command.html

Comment: Yes, that works! However, this is probably not what Android developers intented to use directly. We can't debug the app from Eclipse this way.

Comment: Good point. I think there is a way to connect the debugger to an already running app, but that may be inconvenient.  You may be able to find a way to modify the eclipse launch implementation; at an extreme iirc the android eclipse plugin is open source ;-)

Comment: FYI that I submitted a feature request for this: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53778

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want to just write some proper tests for this purpose. 
Take a look at this: 
[Android Testing fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/testing/testing_android.html)

You could then be running your test during development, which would launch the Activity as you want it.